# perl - how work while loop on this program

Tags: perl

I have this code but I don't understand how it works specifically this `$counts{$user}{$program}++;`

```
my %counts;

open my $IN, '<', 'SESSION.txt' or die;
while (<$IN>) {
  next if length ($_) < 51;
  my ($sid, $user, $terminal, $program) = unpack 'A9 @11 A25 @37 A15 @53 A25';

  next if $sid eq '---------';  # you need some way to filter out bogus or header rows

  $program =~ s/\(.+//;         # based on your example, turn toto (fifi) into toto

  $counts{$user}{$program}++; #how that work ?
}
#close $IN;

while (my ($user, $ref) = each %counts) {
  while (my ($program, $count) = each %$ref) {
    print "User = $count $user with program $program\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

`$counts{$user}{$program}++;` increments the value stored at key `$program` in a nested hash which is stored (by reference) as the value of `$counts{$user}`.

When perl sees the expression `$counts{$user}{$program}` it will create the (nested) hash stored in `$counts{$user}` if it does not exist yet. This is called 'autovivification'. perl will also create a key `$program`in this (nested) hash if it does not exist yet and set its value to undef.

If the value at `$counts{$user}{$program}` is not yet defined when you call `++` on it, perl will assume, you want a number in this slot and initialize it with 0.